# Run a jar file from php and manage the exceptions?

Tags: java, php, jar, jsoup

I have a jar file which uses Jsoup library, and when i launch it, it opens a website, and the jar output a simple line from that website.
To access it from my personnal website, i call it with the `exec()` php function. Most of the time, this works perfectly and the output is well displayed. But, sometimes, i have nothing. I launched the jar many times from a ssh session, and i saw that, about 5% of the time, i have an error message, with an `Exception in thread "main"`, caused by `java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out`. 
I think that maybe the site takes too much time to respond and java just interrupt the program. How could I manage this ? From my php or from my jar ?
Saying that while i have not output, i have to run the jar again. I was thinking of doing it whithin the php, but i think it would be better to manage it directly in the jar.
Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be rather incerasing the timeout for Jsoup in the jar instead of retrying to execute the jar. Without knowing the code of the java app using jsoup. but there should be an entry like: `Connection con = Jsoup.connect("the page url")` this is where the jsoup connection is created. The default timeout according to the [docs](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/Connection.html) is `3` seconds.
You can increase this timeout to a higher value like 5 seconds (please note that the method expects milliseconds):

```
con.timeout(5000);
```

Or without the local variable:

```
Jsoup.connect("the page url").timeout(5000).get()
```

Comment: Even with 20sec, i still have that error, like i have to run my jar 1 or 2 times before it really works.
The php which call it now has a loop which executes the jar until it gives an output :
`while(empty($output)){
  exec("java -jar check_nfo.jar ", $output);
  sleep(5);
 }`

Comment: you could try to set a really high value lile 10 minutes to see if it is really a timeout issue

Comment: Thanks, you're the best ! With a high value, it works ;)